# Remapping Boybu Keybinds for a Chromebook

Tags: chromebook, byobu

I am trying to remap my the F keys in byobu to match the icons on my chrome book.  I started by editing my keybindings as follows:

```
$ cat ~/.byobu/keybindings
source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/common
escape ^Bb

# F-keys seem to work well in both gnome-terminal and tty consoles
bindkey -k k1 eval 'prev' 'fit'               # F1  | Previous Window
bindkey -k k2 eval 'next' 'fit'               # F2  | Next Window
bindkey -k k3 copy                            # F3  | Enter copy/scrollback mode
bindkey -k k4 $BYOBU_BACKEND                  # F4  | Create new window
bindkey -k k5 eval 'process x' 'process t'    # F5  | Re-title a window
bindkey -k k6 eval 'process x' 'process r'    # F6  | Reload profile
```

But when I restart byobu nothing appears to have changed.

```
$ byobu -v
byobu version 5.17
tmux 1.6
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:cxx-3.0-amd64:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-amd64:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-amd64:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-amd64:cxx-4.0-noarch:desktop-3.1-amd64:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-amd64:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-amd64:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-3.2-amd64:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch:qt4-3.1-amd64:qt4-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I needed to make my edits in keybindings.tmux.

```
$ cat ~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux 
set -g prefix F12
unbind-key -n C-a

bind-key -n F1 previous-window
bind-key -n F2 next-window
bind-key -n F3 copy-mode
bind-key -n F4 new-window \; rename-window ""
bind-key -n C-F4 display-panes \; split-window -h
bind-key -n S-F4 display-panes \; split-window -v
bind-key -n F5 command-prompt -p "(rename-window)" "rename-window %%"
unbind-key -n F6
```

Works great and maps the keys to vaguely match the icons on a chromebook pixels F keys.

Comment: If you use Byobu from linux as well, will this change the standard linux commands up as well?

Comment: Yes, it modifies the settings for any client